# tex.sx Website Status

Tags: support

All day, I have been unable to display any graphics that are included in tex.stackexchange questions and answers.  I figured there was something scrogged on the website and that it would remedy itself.  Now, 9 hours later, as questions continue to be asked and answered, I'm not sure if it is a website issue or if my system is merely blocking graphics from the site.

While the here and now question concerns the current issue, the more general question would be how does one learn of website functional status from the website itself?  Is there a place I can check to see if the website thinks itself to be fully operational?

Comment: can't help with how to find anything out, but i can confirm that there has been a slowdown in the transfer of *something* most of the day.  a few times i've looked down in the lower left-hand corner of the browser window (while the "still working" icon was spinning) and seen a reference to an address in the facebook domain.  it seems to have subsided for the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Network-wide status is viewable on the [Stack Exchange Network Status](http://stackstatus.net/) (or on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackStatus)).

As for images not loading, on occasion... this is something that is independent of the SE network, as images are embedded from the host. So, if IMGUR is experiencing connectivity issues, it will most likely translate to you experiencing image viewing problems.

Troubleshooting could include restarting your browser, clearing the cache, or even viewing the contents through another browser. If none of these techniques yield any clue to why things aren't working the way they're supposed to, enter the lion's den on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com) or [the Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) and query the "Who's Who".

Comment: Thank you.  The problem appears to be that my system is blocking images from imgur.com.  Now to get tech support to remedy that...